# Android Wear 2.0 vs Android - limitation

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I'm actually writing my Bachelor thesis about the capability of Android Wear 2.0. I've already done some small apps with the Watch (independent from the phone ), coding in JAVA.

So my question is:

Programmatically (in JAVA), what are the limitation about the Android Wear 2.0 compared to the Android OS?

For example, I've seen we cannot use webView because it's not supported by the Wear OS. But I can't find other limitation.

And sorry for my bad English.

Thanks,

Christ

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/index.html

Comment: Oh, I've missed this. Perfect,  thank you.